# Copy database schema from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, backup, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downgrading from SQL Server 2008 to 2005](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47/downgrading-from-sql-server-2008-to-2005)

Is it possible to copy the database schema from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2005,

I don't need data from the tables, just the empty database structure with triggers, stored procedures, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't using any SQL2008+ only features (e.g. compression) you will be able to script out the objects you require and execute in SQL2005. If you're not sure if any SQL2008+ features are in use, trial and error (script and execute, see what happens) will soon tell you where the problems are.

This is very different to restoring a backup from 2008 to 2005, which is not possible.