# Downgrade backup from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, backup

Im trying to restore my database on my server, but i got the following error:

> The database was backed up on a server running version 12.00.2269.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   version 11.00.2100. Either restore the database on a server that
>   supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this
>   server.

So I need to downgrade my backup file, but how can I do it? Do I need to install a new instance of SQL Server 2014? With the option "Tasks -> Backup" there is no option to select the version for the backup.

Thanks!

Comment: You have two options for this: 1) Upgrade your destination environment to SQL Server 2014 or 2) If upgrade is not possible use generate scripts option to transfer your data from 2014 to 2012.

Comment: If you have  2012 environment, this is the way to do it. However it might be better to run it on a 2014 environment. https://swyssql.wordpress.com/2016/02/23/migration-gone-wrong-the-fallback-scenario/

Answer (score 1):

As per the message you got you were trying to restore backup taken from SQL Server 2014 database on SQL Server 2012 which of course is not allowed.

> So I need to downgrade my backup file, but how can I do it?

You cannot downgrade a backup file, neither can you downgrade, inplace, the database from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2012. You only have option to move database objects and data from SQL Server 2014 to 2012. You can refer to answers given on [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55055/how-to-move-a-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-sql-server-2005) and  [This SE thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47/downgrading-from-sql-server-2008-to-2005) to know how to move data and objects. The links are not specific to your version of database but methods would be the same.

> Do I need to install a new instance of SQL Server 2012

No it would not be new version of 2012 but new version of SQL Server 2014. If you don't want to follow above method then yes you would have to install new SQL Server 2014 server and then you can restore database on it. But I would suggest you follow advise given above. Installing 2012 would require new license.

Comment: @Shanky But I want to change it to SQL Server 2012. The server I have in my local computer is SQL Server 2014, the one I have in the server is SQL Express 2012. On the server Im only allowed to back up and restore the database in the control panel. So I thought I have to do it locally: install SQL Server 2012 on my local machine, and then run the script that I created in the 2014 edition. Is that right?